# Как сделать переадресацию после авторизации?

Tags: html, ucoz

Кто делал сайты на юкозе, знают, что после авторизации на сайте - форма авторизации закрывается, и всё. Подскажите, плиз, как сделать, чтобы после авторизации форма закрывалась и тебя перебрасывало на определённую страницу?

Answer (score 1):

на html:
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; URL=http://myurl.com">